# Is there any way to save each user app data in android without authentication

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to save user app data in android without authentication. Actually, I am working on an Android app. In this app user purchase in app coins when the app is reinstalled or app data are cleared the user data is also deleted. I am using Firebase in this app but I want to save user's data without authentication.

Is there any way to do this

Comment: After first time that user enter your app, all the data he/she has changed will be saved in his/her account

Comment: You can save user data to the phone, but if they uninstall the app they wont be able  to recover it. If you want to be able to recover a specific users data you will need some form of authentication.